# Saving images using Opencv in python

Tags: python, opencv

Is there a better way to rewrite this part in python. It doesnot have to be shorter as long as its much better. thanks in advance

```
count = 1
while count < 10:
    _, pho = webcam.read()
    gr = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    images = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gr, 1.3, 4)
    for (x,y,w,h) in faces: 
            cv2.rectangle(pho,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)
            fa = gray[y:y + h, x:x + w]
            e_size = cv2.resize(fa, (100, 100))
            cv2.imwrite('%s/%s.JPEG' % (folder,count), e_size)
    count += 1
    cv2.imshow('OpenCV', pho)
    key = cv2.waitKey(20)
```

Answer (score 2):

A very simple change that replaces the while loop with a for loop (I don't know much about OpenCV, so I can't help too much there):

```
for count in range(1, 10):
    _, pho = webcam.read()
    gr = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    images = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gr, 1.3, 4)
    for (x,y,w,h) in faces: 
            cv2.rectangle(pho,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)
            fa = gray[y:y + h, x:x + w]
            e_size = cv2.resize(fa, (100, 100))
            cv2.imwrite('%s/%s.JPEG' % (folder,count), e_size)
    cv2.imshow('OpenCV', pho)
    key = cv2.waitKey(20)
```

Additionally, in Python 3 especially, the `%` string formatting syntax is out-of-favor/deprecated -- use the `{}` and `.format` syntax instead:

```
cv2.imwrite('%s/%s.JPEG' % (folder,count), e_size)
```

becomes

```
cv2.imwrite('{!s}/{!s}.JPEG'.format(folder, count), e_size)
```